# Stimulsoft JS viewer

Tags: stimulusjs

I added the mrt file but it won't show the report and images. It seems nothing is working![enter image description here][1]

Here is the code. I'm really confused with stimulsoft.

```
    var report = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();

  report.loadFile("../report.mrt");

  var options = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewerOptions();

  options.width = "1000px";

  options.height = "1000px";

  options.appearance.htmlRenderMode =
    Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiHtmlExportMode.Div;

  options.appearance.scrollbarsMode = true;

  options.appearance.backgroundColor =
    Stimulsoft.System.Drawing.Color.dodgerBlue;

  options.appearance.showTooltips = false;

  options.toolbar.showPrintButton = false;

  options.toolbar.showDesignButton = false;

  options.toolbar.showAboutButton = false;

  options.exports.showExportToPdf = true;

  options.exports.ShowExportToWord2007 = true;

  var viewer = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(options);

  viewer.report = report;
```